Google OAuth via Server is working fine on local server with microservices architecture in spring boot but it does not works on staging server
I am facing an issue while testing Google OAuth via Server in staging server while using spring boot microservices architecture but it works fine with the local server.
In my Google Console redirect URL of staging is configured in the same way I set for local. If there is need to configure any other configurations for my staging I don't know. Need suggestion about this issue. Thanks!

In both cases local and staging, I am getting request of "Info" from "Google" by passing through my gateway service to my auth-service: Confirmed by debugging the staging auth service. I'll attach the screenshot of my controller method that is receiving null OAuth2User request data in case of staging server but the actual data is coming in local server. I think this is the issue that we have to fix: 
Furthermore: I am using Server based google OAuth so I don't think there would be need to put anything in Authorized JavaScript origins or maybe I have to I don't know. 
